# unable to update displayName using firebase.auth().currentUser.updateProfile

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic2, firebase-authentication

I'm using ionic2 + firebase now.
After I `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`, I tried to update the displayName using `firebase.auth().currentUser.updateProfile` 
However, when I try to log `firebase.auth().currentUser.providerData`, the displayName is still null.
Anyone can tell me what did I overlook?
Below is my code;

```
const name = form.value.name //e.g james

var user = firebase.auth().currentUser
console.log('name: '+name) //manage to print "name: james"
user.updateProfile({
  displayName: name,
  photoURL: ''
}).then(function(){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(user.providerData))
  //it print "displayName":null
}, function(error){
  console.log(error)
});
```

Comment: Can you try signing the user out and in again? That will likely refresh their profile.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, you are right, the data in providerData was not update when i log it immediately after user.updateProfile

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen However, shouldn't the data be update in realtime? Why I still need to sign in and sign out again? 
I couldnt tell user they need to sign in and sign out in order to have their displayName updated, right?

Comment: The profile only refreshes once once the token refreshes. I actually thought we'd fixed that in recent SDK versions, so make sure you're on the latest version.

Comment: I tried update the firbase to 3.9.0, but problem persist

Comment: Hmm, it seems to update the top level displayName only. However calling reload() on user should update it in providerData. Will report this to Firebase Auth team.